# Jquery menu - controlling carousel with hash links

Tags: jquery, mmenu, owl-carousel

I have a mmenu set up - but it seems to ignore all hash links (#one, #teo etc) when they are within list items in the menu.

I want to be able to comtrol a carousel from the mmenu.

If I take them outside of the list items, they work, but the formatting of the mmenu is lost, and also the mmenu no longer closes after clicking!

See demo:
http://demo.tyga.co.uk/easyjet/index.htm

Is there an option to allow hash URLs in the menu to move the carousel slides forward?

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mmenu plugin prevents the default behavior of anchors (inside lists) when its href starts with (or is equal to) "#".
You can override this behavior by changing the onClick options:

```
$("#menu").mmenu({
    onClick: {
       close: true,
       preventDefault: false,
       setSelected: true
    }
});
```

By the way, all of this does not apply to anchors with either [rel="external"] or [target="_blank"].

Comment: I just tried the above on a right side menu - but it doesn't work...

$(function() {
$("#menu-right").mmenu({
offCanvas : {
position : 'right'
},
     
onClick: {
close: true,
preventDefault: false,
setSelected: true
}
});
});

Have I missed something obvious?


Andy

Comment: I've just realised the problem is related to the NAV being wrapped in a UL - but I have only one item, so can it work without the list items in place?

Comment: The plugin doesn't do anything with anchors that aren't inside a list item.
The "menu" does not need to be a NAV or UL, you can use DIVs as well.

Comment: Thanks. It's just that the sidebar only closes automatically if wrapped in a ul

Answer (score 0):

I think the mmenu is overwriting the ability to navigate via hash URLs, to fix this, you can change your URLs to be page-hash URLs.

So

```
<a href="#five">Five</a>
```

Becomes

```
<a href="index.htm#five">Five</a>
```

Which works.

Comment: Thanks - I just tried this - it works - but it doesn't now close the sidebar after clicking - which I want to still happen. See below: http://demo.tyga.co.uk/andy/index.htm

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919555/mmenu-not-closing-on-anchor-tags